# Converted to and form UTF8 after SHA256 yields different results, why?

Tags: c#, utf-8, sha256

```
var test = "sdfsdfsdfasfwerqwer";

var q = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);

var sha256 = SHA256.Create();

var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(q);

var z = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash);

var t = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(z);
```

In the above example, hash and t have different values. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hash` is not an UTF-8 encoded byte array, just some random bytes. Note: not all byte arrays are valid as UTF-8, UTF-8 has its own rules. Therefore, it cannot necessarily be decoded into a string. (Specifically, invalid bytes are usually decoded into a question mark in .NET.)

You can try a regular 8-bit encoding which supports all possible byte arrays, like ISO-8859-1. Of course you will still get garbage when you try to read that as a string, but it should work back and forth.

If you are trying to transfer a random byte array as a string, I suggest you use BASE-64 encoding, which converts byte arrays to an ASCII string, which should be safe in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll go with that then!